# Wordpress function is not mobile

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get an if statement in wordpress if the page is frontpage and that the page isn't mobile. That's what I tried so far:

```
<?php if ( !wp_is_mobile() ) {elseif ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) { ?> .. <?php } } ?>
```

But it doesen't work.
Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code with that `elseif` statement inside the `if` block. It would be like this:

```
<?php if ( !wp_is_mobile() && ( is_home() || is_front_page() )) { ?> .. <?php } ?>
```